# Getting only alphabets and some punctuations from pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, data-science

This is the output i got from a pandas data frame I have generated using the code

```
df.loc[:,'body'].head()
```

```
0    Thanks for the advice! Ill try to open it as s...
1    Sometimes it will only feel wet or damp when t...
2    21M, sounds like you’re in uni. How are you do...
3               Nick and Amy's r/s so bloody toxic sia
4    no probs! Okay so my method is using a disposa...
```

I would like to do two things here. Firstly, I would like to be able to see my entire row sentence because it is too long and it is followed by a '...'. Secondly, I would only like to collect data which is textual and some important punctuations such as ',.!/'. How do I do this?

Comment: You can set pandas option `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',1000)` to increase column width.

Comment: post ur expected output

Comment: could also try: `print(df.loc[:,'body'].head().to_string())